# Best interface to create a resource and return it to be released by the caller

Tags: c++, raii

I have a `char*` array that is `new`'d and initialized in a function. Normally I'd use `std::string` but the array is null terminated with possibly more than one `'\0'` and I would like to capture the full size.

As it is, the Caller must remember to `delete[]` the `char *` when it uses this function. I'd like to clean up the interface so that `delete[]` is called in a destructor when it goes out of scope but I'm unsure of what to use. Is there a smart pointer than can take a `char *`?

Edit:

Id rather not use `std::string` as it would be unclear that this isnt a C-style null terminated string. Can I use a `boost::scoped_array<char>` for this? Since `scoped_array` is non-copyable how would I return it from the function that created it?

Comment: `std::string` **can** contain null characters. And if you're really that frightened, you can always use a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, `std::string` has the implication that it can be used as a regular null-terminated string with the `c_str` method. I think your recommendation of `std::vector<char>` is better in this case, unless you have need of some of the string functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The utility of `string::c_str()`, `string::data()` and `vector<char>::data()` is almost identical. You just have to train your consumer to not treat nulls specially...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I really am just talking about an expectation of how it should be used, not a technical limitation. Principle of least astonishment and all that - you wouldn't expect a `std::string` to contain a null, so to avoid confusion you don't let it even if it's perfectly capable.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am with Kerrek here, if the semantics of the interface are that *strings* can contain NUL characters, then it is sensible to expect users to make use of `std::string::length()` and `std::string::data()`. In the same way that if you have a `std::map<int,T>` for a type `T` that is not default constructible users must be aware not to use `operator[]`, it is just a limitation on the particular use of the component.

Answer (score 1):

This is what OO programming is all about.  Use `std::string` like comment above, or create a class that handles the data for you:

```
class MyObj {
private:
   char *data;
   int len;

public:
   MyObj( const char *data, int len ) {
      this->data = new char[...
      // do what you need here
   }

   const char* getStr() const {
      return data;
   }

   int getLen() const {
      return len;
   }

   ~MyObj() {
      delete [] data;
   }
};
```

You'll probably also want to implement copy constructor and assignment operator (or privatize their use)...

Alternatively, use std::string as your base implementation but only expose what and how you want:

```
class MyObj : private std::string {
public:
   // whatever you want here
   const char* data() {
      return c_str();
   }

   int length() const {
      return std::string::length();
   }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget the Rule of Three (and if using C++11, a move constructor and move assignment would be a good idea too).

Comment: Thanks for the post but a custom class seems overboard for this. Its only a char[]. My question is mainly how can I use RAII correctly here an is there a smart pointer that would make sense. I am not using c++11

Comment: @Chris, understood, and I don't know the rest of your code, but you might also look at your problem from a different angle.  Perhaps the "function" that's creating this data should be a member method of the `MyObj` object itself?  Or perhaps it *is* the object's constructor?  I find myself rethinking code/data layouts in situations such as yours...

Comment: Specifically, this can't be used as a return value for a function without correct copy or move semantics; in which case you're reinventing either `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Totally agree.  I'd either pass by reference, or have the function be an object member (or constructor), or not use a custom class at all.

Answer (score 0):

Before 2011, your choices for returning a dynamic array from a function were `std::string`, `std::vector<char>` or `boost::shared_array<char>`. With a modern implementation, you could also use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

I'd recommend using `std::string` to represent a string.